# Using same Ajax function to return content into multiple divs

Tags: javascript, ajax

We have a js ajax call we are using to pull content and placing them in different divs on our page.

We have been creating a new function for each call, but would like to just use one function for them all. In attempting this - it only updates the last div position requested.

Here are the requests:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        sendRequestFS('http://ourdomain.com/somepage.html', 'csad');
        sendRequestFS('http://ourdomain.com/somepage1.html', 'fsad');
        sendRequestFS('http://ourdomain.com/somepage2.html', 'tilead');
    </script>
```

The divs on the page:

```
<div id = 'csad'>CS Here</div>
<div id = 'fsad'>FS Here</div>
<div id = 'tilead'>Tiles Here</div>
```

And the function that we are using ... is there some way to use this same function each time?

```
function createRequestObjectFS() 
{
    var returnObj = false;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        returnObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            returnObj = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
            try {
            returnObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {}
            }

    }
    return returnObj;
}
var httpFS = createRequestObjectFS();
var targetFS;
// This is the function to call, give it the script file you want to run and
// the div you want it to output to.
function sendRequestFS(scriptFileFS, targetElementFS)
{   
    targetFS = targetElementFS;
    try{
//      alert ("RQFS File: " + scriptFileFS + " Target : " + targetElementFS);
    httpFS.open('get', scriptFileFS, true);
    }
    catch (e){
    document.getElementById(targetFS).innerHTML = e;
    return;
    }
    httpFS.onreadystatechange = handleResponseFS;
    httpFS.send();  
}
function handleResponseFS()
{   

    if(httpFS.readyState == 4) {        
    try{
    //    alert ("HRQFS");
        var strResponseFS = httpFS.responseText;
        document.getElementById(targetFS).innerHTML = strResponseFS;
        } catch (e){
        document.getElementById(targetFS).innerHTML = e;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `targetFS` is a global variable. You have to create a new `onreadystatechange` function for each request.

Comment: So something like:  `if (targetFS == 'fsad') {
     httpFS.onreadystatechange = handleResponseFS;
  } else if (targetFS == 'csad') {
  httpFS.onreadystatechange = handleResponseCS;
  }`
And then have multiple handleResponse functions:
` function handleResponseFS()
 function handleResponseCS()`

Comment: No, that would reduce the usefulness of the function a lot. Use a closure: `httpFS.onreadystatechange = function() { /* access targetElementFS here */ };` Similarly, `httpFS` should not be global and you should create a new request for every function call. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started. It has a couple of examples and also explains this kind of solution.

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged your functions to make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/q2Za2/1/

```
function createRequestObjectFS() 
{
    var returnObj = false;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        returnObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            returnObj = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
            try {
            returnObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {}
            }

    }
    return returnObj;
}

// This is the function to call, give it the script file you want to run and
// the div you want it to output to.
function sendRequestFS(scriptFileFS, targetElementFS)
{   
    var httpFS = createRequestObjectFS();
    var targetFS;
    function handleResponseFS()
    {   

        if(httpFS.readyState == 4) {        
            try {
                //alert ("HRQFS");
                var strResponseFS = httpFS.responseText;
                document.getElementById(targetFS).innerHTML = strResponseFS;
            } catch (e){
                document.getElementById(targetFS).innerHTML = e;
            }   
        }
    }
    targetFS = targetElementFS;
    try{
//      alert ("RQFS File: " + scriptFileFS + " Target : " + targetElementFS);
    httpFS.open('get', scriptFileFS, true);
    }
    catch (e){
    document.getElementById(targetFS).innerHTML = e;
    return;
    }
    httpFS.onreadystatechange = handleResponseFS;
    httpFS.send();  


}


sendRequestFS('https://r3dux.com/test_files/1.php', 'csad');
sendRequestFS('https://r3dux.com/test_files/2.php', 'fsad');
sendRequestFS('https://r3dux.com/test_files/3.php', 'tilead');
```